# How to check for goroutine completion while actively reading from channel?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

Had a hard time expressing this question in a sentence. Here is the situation:

I'm trying to spawn off a set of goroutines to recurse over directories and find matching files. Then I collect those files and continue on to process them. However, the catch is that I don't know how many files each routine will find, so I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the main thread to exit once all the routines are done

I could just make the channel buffer crazy big but that's not a good solution, this tool doesn't need to be 100% robust but good enough where it's not breaking all the time. Plus there's a chance it could turn up a lot of files

```
// start a routine to traverse each directory
fpchan := make(chan string, 100)
for _, dir := range numDirs {
    fmt.Printf("Searching for file in %s\n", dir)
    go findLogs(searchString, dir, fpchan)
}

// collect filepaths from channel
files := make([]string, 0, maxLogs)
for file := range fpchan { // I'LL GET STUCK WHEN EVERYTHING COMPLETES, NOTHING TO RECEIVE
    if len(files) <= cap(files) {
        files.append(file)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Reached max logfile count of %d\n", maxLogs)
    }
}
```

A waitgroup doesn't really work because the channel could fill up and the routines would be stuck (since I don't know how many results there will be ahead of time)

Is it kosher to send an empty string on the channel as a way for the goroutine to signal "complete"? Like the following:

```
// collect filepaths from channel
files := make([]string, 0, maxLogs)
for file := range fpchan {
    if file == "" {
        fmt.Println("goroutine finished")
        numRunning--
        if numRunning == 0 {
             break
        }
        continue
    }
    if len(files) <= cap(files) {
        files.append(file)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Reached max logfile count of %d\n", maxLogs)
    }
}
```

For this situation since an empty filepath would be invalid, it would work as a poor man's signal. It just feels like a hack for which there should be a better solution I would think

Any way to do this in a way that isn't horribly complicated (bunch of extra channels, non-blocking receives, etc)? If it's much more complicated than this I'd just do them in sequence but I thought it'd be a good chance to take advantage of concurrency

Comment: Your "sentinel" value approach would work, but in my subjective opinion, less elegant than using a WaitGroup. However, don't use an empty string as sentinel value - making a new struct is cheap. Make one that has a `File string` field and a `FindComplete bool` field that act as a sentinel - that is more self-documenting.

Comment: I agree it is less elegant now that I understand the async "waitGroup arbiter" pattern you described. A struct would make my original thought cleaner, I'll put that in my back pocket since I may need it later. Thanks for the tips, I'm new to Go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `WaitGroup` here. But you need to wait for the waitgroup in a goroutine, and in that goroutine you close the channel when the waitgroup has completed, so that your main loop terminates:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
// start a routine to traverse each directory
fpchan := make(chan string, 100)
for _, dir := range numDirs {
    fmt.Printf("Searching for file in %s\n", dir)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(dir string) {
        findLogs(searchString, dir, fpchan)
        wg.Done()
    }(dir)
}

go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(fpchan)
}()
```

(your collection loop over `fpchan` remains the same)

Comment: That was my first thought. However, let's say I make the channel buffer 20 in size. If my routines find 21 files, they'll block on send and never finish, so neither will the waitgroup (unless I'm understanding them wrong)

Comment: Why would it block? Your loop that consumes `fpchan` runs in parallel with the producers. The `wg.Wait()` is done inside a separate goroutine. And it signals your consumption loop by closing the channel. No individual producer goroutine knows whether the others have finished, so none of them could decide when to close the channel - you need a seperate arbiter for that, and that is what the goroutine that does the `wg.Wait()` acts as.

Comment: Ohhhh I understand your point now. So the wait group is also resolved async. Thank you, this is what I was looking for :)